# Why are the properties of my view model not displaying?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using the MVC 4 Beta but this doesn't appear to be specific to MVC 4. I'm new to MVC so this is probably just me needing to be pointed in the right direction. Thanks!

I'm using a view model defined as...

```
public class PatientWithVisits
{
    public Patient Patient { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Visit> Visits { get; set; }

}
```

In my view, I'm using the HTML helper (`LabelFor`, in this case) and passing my properties via lambda expressions, like this `@Html.LabelFor(model => model.VisitId)`.

I started digging and quickly I realized my mistake. The view model doesn't have a `VisitId` property. However, fixing the problem didn't come as easy as finding the problem.

I tried changing `model => model.VisitId` to `model => model.Visits.VisitId` but that didn't work. The intellisense for `model` includes `Patient` and `Visits` as I expected. However, `Visits` did not contain any of the properties I was expecting to see for a `Visit`, like `VisitId`. The intellisense for the `Visits` collection contained only extension methods.

What is going on and how do I get the properties of my `Visit` to display?

Comment: The Visits property is a collection of Visit, so you need to iterate to access its properties. If you want to test it without iterating you could try this model => model.Visits.First().VisitId

Answer (score 1):

Visits is a collection, but each individual `Visit` in the collection will have a `VisitId`. To simply display them as requested:

```
@foreach (var visit in Model.Visits)
{
    @visit.VisitId
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add a property to your ViewModel called ViewId

Comment: I'm confused. Each `Visit` in the `List<Visit>` has a VisitId. What am I missing about this?

Comment: To use the HTML helpers, your VisitId has to be available without drilling down into an object properties to retrieve it.